# jQuery combine toggle with click

Tags: jquery

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/sxqwp/1/

My question is when I press 'close' then press 'toggle' nothing happens, after second click shows text. When I click 'toggle' it hides text then I click 'open' it shows text but when click again 'toggle' it still shows etc. How can I fix this

what if something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/sxqwp/6/

```
$("a").toggle(
  function () {
      $('p').animate({width: "200px"});
  },
  function () {
    $('p').animate({width: "100px"});
  }
);


$("a.openA").click(function() {
    $('p').stop().animate({width: "200px"});
});


$("a.closeA").click(function() {
    $('p').stop().animate({width: "100px"});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By not messing with the toggle function. :)
http://jsfiddle.net/sxqwp/2/

```
$("a").click( function() { 
    $('p').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Just was typing the exact same answer +1 :)

Comment: probably should add a(.toggle?) class to the toggle link as well - little weird that any a tag would run the toggle.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use the `.toggleClass()` method:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

$("a").click(function() {
    $('p').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

**HTML CODE:**

```
<a href="#demo" class="nav-toggle">Toggle</a>
<a href="#demo" class='nav-open'>Open</a>
<a href="#demo" class='nav-close'>Close</a>

<div id="demo" style="display:none;">
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Good Bye</p>
</div>
```

**JQUERY SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
    var content_toggle= $(this).attr('href');                    
    $(content_toggle).slideToggle('slow');
 });

   $('.nav-open').click(function(){
     var content_show = $(this).attr('href');                    
     $(content_show).slideDown();
  });

   $('.nav-close').click(function(){
      var content_hide = $(this).attr('href');                    
      $(content_hide).slideUp();
  });
});
```

view live eg. - http://jsfiddle.net/sxqwp/11/